# vb.net ditect title bar color in windows10

Tags: vb.net, forms, custom-titlebar, systemcolors

I am trying to make a title-bar less form add form then add following code

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = ""
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    End Sub
```

but how i find title bar color for add it "upper_panel" in my form.

[image]

Comment: So sizable form with out a title bar?  That what you’re looking for?

Comment: You included the tag "systemcolors", what have you already tried to do with system colors?  Have you done a search to see how you might be able to get/set them?